# How to get the http_Listener.hostname in azure terraform

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-azure

Here's my application gateway terraform template:

```
resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "appgw" {
  name                = "${var.client_name_prefix}${var.environment_name}${var.location_abr}gw${var.instance}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = var.location
  enable_http2        = true

  backend_http_settings {
    name                                = "backOfficeAppHttpSetting"
    cookie_based_affinity               = "Disabled"
    port                                = var.backed_port
    protocol                            = "Http"
    probe_name                          = "nginx-ingress-prob"
    request_timeout                     = var.backend_request_timeout_back_office
    pick_host_name_from_backend_address = false
    host_name                           = "local.backoffice.${var.sslcert}"
    affinity_cookie_name                = "ApplicationGatewayAffinity"
  }

  http_listener {
    name                           = "backOfficeAppListener"
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = local.frontend_ip_configuration_name
    frontend_port_name             = local.frontend_port_443_name
    protocol                       = "Https"
    host_name                      = "${var.client_name}-${var.environment_name}-admin.${var.sslcert}"
    require_sni                    = true
    ssl_certificate_name           = var.sslcert
  }

  http_listener {
    name                           = "frontWebAppListener"
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = local.frontend_ip_configuration_name
    frontend_port_name             = local.frontend_port_443_name
    protocol                       = "Https"
    host_name                      = "${var.client_name}-${var.environment_name}.${var.sslcert}"
    require_sni                    = true
    ssl_certificate_name           = var.sslcert
  }
}
```

And In key-vault.tf. I want to create to secret in which I want to save the value of **first http_listener (HOSTNAME)**.
BUT, I'm unable to get it. Is there any way to get **http_listener.host_name?**
I want to know is there any way to get it.
I have tried it but i couldn't get it.

Comment: Have you tried something like `azurerm_application_gateway.appgw.http_listener[0].id`?

Comment: No, its doesnt work.

Comment: What does that mean? You get no output or the output is not what you need? You can also try `azurerm_application_gateway.appgw.http_listener[0].host_name`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case where I used a for-expression.

Given `httplstn` as listener name, this output specification

```
output "GATEWAY_LISTENER_HOSTNAME" {
  value = "${[for l in azurerm_application_gateway.gw.http_listener : l.host_name if l.name == "httplstn"][0]}"
}
```

or

```
output "GATEWAY_LISTENER_HOSTNAME" {
  value = "${one([for l in azurerm_application_gateway.gw.http_listener : l.host_name if l.name == "httplstn"])}"
}
```

should give you a result like

```
Outputs:

GATEWAY_LISTENER_HOSTNAME = "testhost"
```